# Realm: Get name field from result

Tags: android, database, realm

I'm trying to get the name property from a result. Looked everywhere and can't figure it out. When I log.d, I get this:

> [Person{id=0, name='Jonathon', age=21}]

How do I access only the name, but not the full result?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Person person = realm.createObject(Person.class);
            person.setName("Jonathon");
            person.setAge(21);
        }
    });

    RealmQuery<Person> query = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("name", "Jonathon");
    RealmResults<Person> result = query.findAll();

    Log.d("Result", result.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RealmQuery<Person> query = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("name", "Jonathon");
RealmResults<Person> result = query.findAll();

Person person = result.get(0);
Log.d("Result", person.getName());
```

Comment: This will lead to crash if there is no record.

Comment: Well I assumed you know what you're looking for considering there was an `executeTransaction` statement just above it

Comment: my friend as per question you're right! But what if he changes the name from "Jonathon" to something else inside `RealmQuery`?  my point is just to avoid run-time crash.

Comment: Then he should be aware of what he's doing. If he crashes during development, at least he'll learn from it :p

Comment: Hello! What does .get(0) do?

Comment: Get the item from the list from the 0th index

Comment: Alrighty. So, how would I select all people from the database?

Comment: `realm.where(Person.class).findAll()`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your query is working fine.

```
List<Person> result = realm.where(HomeJob.class).equalTo("name", "Jonathon").findAll();
    // you can use `RealmResults` as per your requirement


for (Person p :
            result) {
        Log.d("Result", "person name: "+p.getName());

    }
```